# Wireless Authentication through Website

Tags: 14.04, networking

Our WiFi network at our university requires you to go to a website and enter a username and password to authenticate. When I try to connect to the WiFi network I get the "Wi-Fi Network Authentication Required" box, I put in the username and password to my domain account, and try to connect but it comes back with "No Certificate Authority certificate chosen" window where I can "Choose CA Certificate", but that is blank.

**Edit:**
I have a HP Mini-210-1170NR, running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I'm guessing it has something to do with after the username and password windows tries to authenticate, something is popping up that additional window.

I get this window to authenticate:

[image]

After filling in the information, this next screen pops up:

[image]

Selecting "Choose CA Certificate" just asks for a file name, and the ignore button just goes back to the Wi-Fi Network screen.

Comment: What comes back with that Certificate Authority thing? What version of Ubuntu are you on? What's your laptop model?

Answer (score 0):

This can solve your problem:
1) Go to "/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt" and Add that as my certificate.After that:
Go to "Edit Connections" and select my wireless connection.Then  went to "General" tab and untick "All users may connect to this network" 
OR
2) Select Protected EAP (PEAP) for authentication mode, and ignored choosing a certificate file.